# How to extract the content of the first paragraph in html response react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am working on a react native project and I have an html string json api response.
I am using react-native-render-html to render it, and I can get all paragraphs and apply specific things like number of lines ,etc.. . However I want to get only the first paragraph in the response like text1.

```
str response='<p class="text">text1</p><p>text2</p><p>text3</p>';

or

str response='<p>text1</p><p>text2</p><p>text3</p>';
```

If there is empty text like `<p></p>` at the beginning i want to ignore it and select the next one:

```
str response='<p></p><p class="text">text1</p><p>text2</p><p>text3</p>';
```

Is it possible to write a regular expression to get only the content of first paragraph which is text1 ?

Comment: Don't use RegEx for HTML https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/691711

Answer (score 0):

The following regex should resolve your problem :

```js
const regex = /<p(?:\sclass="[^"]+")?>([^(?:<\/p)]+)<\/p>/i;
const str = '<p>text1</p><p>text2</p><p>text3</p>';

console.log(str.match(regex)[1]);
```

Comment: Hello, it never works can you please recheck the regex .